# How to draw the graphs for these functions?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, graphing-functions

Could I please be helped with the graphs for the following functions:

$$y=\lceil \tan x \rceil, \quad y=\tan (\lceil x \rceil), \quad y=\lceil \tan (\lceil x \rceil) \rceil$$

I have been able to form the graphs for the sine and cosine functions based on the fundamentals of the greatest integer function. However I am having problems with $\tan$ and $\cot$ graphs.

Comment: What do square parens mean?

Comment: @fantini, it's still the same, pls use \lceil \rceil

Comment: I've changed to ceiling then, adding parentheses to avoid confusion.

Comment: What do you mean 'How to draw the graphs'?

Comment: Yeah, I know they still remain the same... could I please be helped with their graphs? I mean where should the original graphs be modified so that  get these movements!

Comment: @Shamayeta, they seem very difficult, use graphing tool

Comment: Do they seem difficult to be plotted on this site or are they difficult themselves?

Comment: difficult themselves, I mean you have to calculate so many points

Comment: However we have got to know these graphs for solving various problems which we have got to tackle every day!

Comment: @Shamayeta, as it was suggested use some plotting software. [One](http://bit.ly/1qXpJ91),[Two](http://bit.ly/1j4bVJN), [Three](http://bit.ly/1j4bX4m).

Comment: I want a theoretical movement for these functions. As these are functions that do exist, I guess they can be plotted rightly. I do not want the exact graphs, but just some ideas through these functions so that I can track their movements...I have done the same for sine and cosine as I have already said. So they must be existing for tan and cot too!!

Answer (score 2):

Start with a graph of $\tan x$. For $\lceil\tan x\rceil$, mark all points of $\tan x$ where the $y$ coordinate is integer. The graph of $\lceil\tan x\rceil$ is a staircase with these points as right ends (because $\tan$ is monotonically increasing ).

For $\tan\lceil x\rceil$, mark th epoints in $\tan x$ with integer $x$ coordinate instead. Again, thes points mark the right ends of the staorcase steps (even across the poles).

For $\bigl\lceil \tan\lceil x\rceil\bigr\rceil$, start with the previous graph and move the steps up to the next integer $y$.

Comment: THanks...this works...May I please ask what the situation would be in case we have a box attached to y too in addition to the RHS?